# Unnesting deep lists after applying the rolling_origin function from the rsample package

Tags: r, dplyr, rsample

I have some data which looks like:

head:

```
  dfID  date       group groupValues
  <chr> <date>     <chr>       <dbl>
1 df1   2020-03-01 grp1       0.175 
2 df1   2020-03-01 grp2       0.150 
3 df1   2020-03-01 grp3       0.0509
```

tail:

```
  dfID  date       group groupValues
  <chr> <date>     <chr>       <dbl>
1 df3   2020-06-29 grp7        0.705
2 df3   2020-06-29 grp8        0.473
3 df3   2020-06-29 grp9        0.900
```

Which is a time series data with 3 unique `dfID`'s and 9 unique `group`'s. Filtering the date column to a single day I have (3 df's and 9 groups):

```
df %>% 
  filter(date == "2020-03-01")

  dfID  date       group groupValues
  <chr> <date>     <chr>       <dbl>
1 df1   2020-03-01 grp1       0.175 
2 df1   2020-03-01 grp2       0.150 
3 df1   2020-03-01 grp3       0.0509
4 df2   2020-03-01 grp4       0.133 
5 df2   2020-03-01 grp5       0.779 
6 df2   2020-03-01 grp6       0.506 
7 df3   2020-03-01 grp7       0.868 
8 df3   2020-03-01 grp8       0.552 
9 df3   2020-03-01 grp9       0.274
```

I next want to split the data up into a pairwise combination of the `dfID`'s.

```
combinedSplit <- combn(levels(as.factor(df$dfID)), m = 2, FUN = function(x)
  df %>% 
    filter(dfID %in% x), simplify = FALSE)

names(combinedSplit) <- combn(levels(as.factor(df$dfID)), m = 2, str_c, collapse="_")
```

So now I have a list of 3 dfs - one for each pairwise combination of the `dfID`'s:

```
df1_df2
df1_df3
df2_df3
```

Now, I want to apply the `rolling_origin` function from the `rsample` package to split the time series into training and testing data. I can naively apply the function by mapping over the lists.

```
rolledData <-  combinedSplit %>% 
  map(., ~ rolling_origin(
    data = .,
    initial = 60,
    assess = 1,
    cumulative = FALSE,
    skip = 0
  )
)
```

I can access the tail of the first split for the combination `df1_df2`.

```
map(rolledData$df1_df2$splits, ~analysis(.x))[[1]] %>% tail()

  dfID  date       group groupValues
  <chr> <date>     <chr>       <dbl>
1 df1   2020-03-19 grp1        0.528
2 df1   2020-03-19 grp2        0.394
3 df1   2020-03-19 grp3        0.532
4 df1   2020-03-20 grp1        0.586
5 df1   2020-03-20 grp2        0.369
6 df1   2020-03-20 grp3        0.153
```

Which is incorrect. In the `rolling_origin` function I stated the training/assessment period to be 60 perids (days) but this data ends on the 20th March. This is because it is taking the first 60 observations of the data not of the time series (3 `group`'s * 20 days).

So I want to apply the `rolling_origin` function to each of the `grp`'s - with each `grp` having 60 day rolling windows.

Here, I thought it would be best to first `nest()` the `group`'s and then apply the `rolling_origin` function, since then each of the `group`'s would be separate and 60 days will correspond to `grp1`, `grp2` and `grp3`. Then, `unnest()` the `group`'s to put `grp1`, `grp2` and `grp3` back into the same data frame.

```
nestedRolledData <- map(combinedSplit, ~group_by(.x, group) %>% 
      nest() %>% 
      mutate(
        rolledData = map(data, ~.x %>% 
                           rolling_origin(
                             data = .,
                             initial = 60,
                             assess = 0,
                             cumulative = FALSE,
                             skip = 0
                           )
                         )
        )
)
```

I am having difficulty with this unnesting.

Inspecting the structure of the lists:

- layer 1 = contains `df1_df2`, `df1_df3` and `df2_df3` combinations.
- layer 2 = contains the nested data with the "rolledData" of interest.
- layer 3 = (expanding `rolledData` contains 6 lists) contains a list for each of the `grp`'s (each `df` das 3 `grp`'s).
- layer 4 = (expanding one of the `grp`'s) contains a `splits` list (generated from the `rolling_origin` function).
- layer 5 = (expanding the `splits` list) contains `[[1]]` ... `[[63]]`. The lists here correspond to each of the `rolling_origin` function training splits. In the `rolling_origin` function I set `initial = 60` and the model creates 63 splits of the data between 2020-03-01 and 2020-06-30. (If I changed `initial = 90` I get 33 splits. So the number of lists here is dependent on the time duration in the data and the `initial` part in the `rolling_origin` function).

I can access the first `splits` using `map(nestedRolledData$df1_df2$rolledData[[1]]$splits, ~analysis(.x))[[1]]` which gives me a data frame of 60 observations starting on `2020-03-01` and ending `2020-04-29`. For the second split in this list `map(nestedRolledData$df1_df2$rolledData[[1]]$splits, ~analysis(.x))[[2]]` I have another data frame containing 60 observations starting this time on the `2020-03-02` and ending on the `2020-04-30` (so this data has been shifted by a single day). I can do this up until `[[63]]` where it starts on `2020-05-02` and ends on `2020-06-30` (which is the last day in my data).

This is what I want - i.e. the data made the correct time series splits for each `grp`. Now I want to unnest these and put them back into the correct data frames. Going back to layer 3 of the list which contains `[[1]], ... , [[6]]` 6 lists. These correspond to each of the 3 groups for the 2 `dfIDs`. So I essentially want to merge these lists together.

If I were to contruct these manually it might look like:

```
# grp 1:6 for rolling_origin split 1
map(nestedRolledData$df1_df2$rolledData[[1]]$splits, ~analysis(.x))[[1]]
map(nestedRolledData$df1_df2$rolledData[[2]]$splits, ~analysis(.x))[[1]]
map(nestedRolledData$df1_df2$rolledData[[3]]$splits, ~analysis(.x))[[1]]
map(nestedRolledData$df1_df2$rolledData[[4]]$splits, ~analysis(.x))[[1]]
map(nestedRolledData$df1_df2$rolledData[[5]]$splits, ~analysis(.x))[[1]]
map(nestedRolledData$df1_df2$rolledData[[6]]$splits, ~analysis(.x))[[1]]

# grp 1:6 for rolling_origin split 2
map(nestedRolledData$df1_df2$rolledData[[1]]$splits, ~analysis(.x))[[2]]
map(nestedRolledData$df1_df2$rolledData[[2]]$splits, ~analysis(.x))[[2]]
map(nestedRolledData$df1_df2$rolledData[[3]]$splits, ~analysis(.x))[[2]]
map(nestedRolledData$df1_df2$rolledData[[4]]$splits, ~analysis(.x))[[2]]
map(nestedRolledData$df1_df2$rolledData[[5]]$splits, ~analysis(.x))[[2]]
map(nestedRolledData$df1_df2$rolledData[[6]]$splits, ~analysis(.x))[[2]]

# ...

# grp 1:6 for rolling_origin split 63
map(nestedRolledData$df1_df2$rolledData[[1]]$splits, ~analysis(.x))[[63]]
map(nestedRolledData$df1_df2$rolledData[[2]]$splits, ~analysis(.x))[[63]]
map(nestedRolledData$df1_df2$rolledData[[3]]$splits, ~analysis(.x))[[63]]
map(nestedRolledData$df1_df2$rolledData[[4]]$splits, ~analysis(.x))[[63]]
map(nestedRolledData$df1_df2$rolledData[[5]]$splits, ~analysis(.x))[[63]]
map(nestedRolledData$df1_df2$rolledData[[6]]$splits, ~analysis(.x))[[63]]
```

Data:

```
library(rsample)
df1 = data.frame(
  date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2020-03-01"), to = as.Date("2020-06-30"), by = "days"),
  grp1 = runif(122),
  grp2 = runif(122),
  grp3 = runif(122)
) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = where(is.numeric), names_to = "group", values_to = "groupValues") %>% 
  add_column(dfID = "df1")

df2 = data.frame(
  date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2020-03-01"), to = as.Date("2020-06-30"), by = "days"),
  grp4 = runif(122),
  grp5 = runif(122),
  grp6 = runif(122)
) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = where(is.numeric), names_to = "group", values_to = "groupValues") %>% 
  add_column(dfID = "df2")

df3 = data.frame(
  date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2020-03-01"), to = as.Date("2020-06-30"), by = "days"),
  grp7 = runif(122),
  grp8 = runif(122),
  grp9 = runif(122)
) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = where(is.numeric), names_to = "group", values_to = "groupValues") %>% 
  add_column(dfID = "df3")

df <- bind_rows(df1, df2, df3) %>% 
  relocate(dfID, .before = date)



map(rolledData$splits, ~analysis(.x))[[1]] %>% tail()

combinedSplit <- combn(levels(as.factor(df$dfID)), m = 2, FUN = function(x)
  df %>% 
    filter(dfID %in% x), simplify = FALSE)

names(combinedSplit) <- combn(levels(as.factor(df$dfID)), m = 2, str_c, collapse="_")

rolledData <-  combinedSplit %>% 
  map(., ~ rolling_origin(
    data = .,
    initial = 60,
    assess = 1,
    cumulative = FALSE,
    skip = 0
  )
)

map(rolledData$df1_df2$splits, ~analysis(.x))[[1]] %>% tail()


nestedRolledData <- map(combinedSplit, ~group_by(.x, group) %>% 
      nest() %>% 
      mutate(
        rolledData = map(data, ~.x %>% 
                           rolling_origin(
                             data = .,
                             initial = 60,
                             assess = 0,
                             cumulative = FALSE,
                             skip = 0
                           )
                         )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be we need a 3 nested `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(rsample)
out <- map(nestedRolledData, ~ map(.x$rolledData, ~ map(.x$splits, analysis)))

str(out, max.level = 3)
#List of 3
# $ df1_df2:List of 6
#  ..$ :List of 63
#  .. ..$ : tibble [60 × 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#  .. ..$ : tibble [60 × 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#  .. ..$ : tibble [60 × 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#  .. ..$ : tibble [60 × 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#  .. ..$ : tibble [60 × 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
# ..
```